# Use variables from other function into the main function C++

Tags: c++

Well, I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void function(char letter){
    if(letter=='k'){
        string line1,line2,line3,line4,line5;
        line1="#   #";
        line2="#   #";
        line3="#### ";
        line4="#   #";
        line5="#   #";
        }
}
int main(){
    function('k');
    cout<<line1;    
}
```

So, I decleared a function called... function, with argument "char letter".
Then I decleared 5 new variables (string type) into the function and gave them a value.

What I'd like to do is to print the content of the variable "line1" into the main function. 
On my mind I thought "I call the function "function" and then it will declare the variable "line1" and fill it by itself."
But of course it doesn't work. Trying to declare the variable "line1" into the main function is also (and obviously) useless, because nothing will happen.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could return the string from the function and either just print it directly or assign it to a string in `main`.

Comment: The way you declare your strings, they're only accessible within the `if` statement. I think you need to look up variable scope.

Comment: This is what classes are for, after all, this is C++: create a class, turn your code into a class method, and class members. Instantiate the class in main, call its method, then access `object.line1`.

Comment: Your variable `line1` was declared in the `if` block in the function `function`. That means that outside of the `if` block, `line1` doesn't exist. You should look up "scope" or "scoping" as a topic in C++. You have to create a variable that is in-scope of the function `main`. Then, you fill that variable with the value returned from `function` or you fill it some other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables have a scope in which they can be referred to. Within a block statement such as your function definition, that (potential) scope extends from the declaration until the end of the block scope (the closing curly brace). `main` is outside of the curly braces where the local variable `line1` was declared, so that variable is out of scope, and cannot be referred to.

Functions can return objects. This part of your function declaration is the type of the object that is returned:

> ```
> void function(char letter) {
> ^^^^
> ```

`void` is a special keyword that means that the function doesn't return anything. We can change the declaration to promise to return a string. And use the return statement to follow through with that promise:

```
std::string function(char letter){
    std::string line1;
    // ...
    return line1;
}
```

We can now create a variable that is local to the `main` function, and initialise it with the value returned from `function`:

```
int main() {
    std::string line1 = function('k')
    std::cout << line1;
```

}

Note that this variable is completely separate from the other variable with the same name in the separate scope.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have another question. What should I do if I want return different variables? For example, I execute the program the first time and I want the variable "line1" to be prited. Then I execute the program a second time and I want the variable "line2" to be printed... etc. etc. 
Forgot to say that all the stuff in the main program are included into a "while", so I need to change the return every time I come back to the while.

Comment: @Jacopo If you want a function to do different things in different calls, you can use function arguments.

Comment: Ok, I'll try out this. Thank you very much again ^ - ^

Answer (score 3):

When you find your self naming variables `line1,line2,line3,line4,line5` you should be using an array or some container instead.

To "get something out of a function" you use the return value.

Putting this two points together we get:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::vector<std::string> function(char letter) {
        if(letter=='k'){
            return { "#   #",
                     "#   #",
                     "#### ",
                     "#   #",
                     "#   #"};
        }
        return {};
}
int main(){
    auto x = function('k');
    std::cout<< x[0];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `line1` ceases to exist when the function ends. You need to `return` it from the function to use it in `main`. Rather than having 5 string variables, you can have a *container* that you insert 5 strings into.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> function(char letter){
    if(letter=='k'){
        return { 
            "#   #",
            "#   #",
            "#### ",
            "#   #",
            "#   #"
        };
    }
    return {};
}
int main(){
    auto lines = function('k');
    std::cout << lines[0]; // the first line, because numbers start at 0
}
```

Comment: better return something in case `letter != 'k'`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `line1` has a scope that is limited to the function `function`. 
In other words means that `line1` **is not accessible** from outside that scope.

If you want to have its value elsewhere you need to return it from the function or declare it as a global, or pass it to the function `function` by reference.

Check the following code to have a sense of what you have to do.

```
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string function(char letter){
    if(letter=='k'){
        string line1,line2,line3,line4,line5;
        line1="#   #";
        line2="#   #";
        line3="#### ";
        line4="#   #";
        line5="#   #";
        return line1;
        }
}

int main(){
    auto line1 = function('k');
    cout<<line1;    
}
```

Also note:

1. `function` is a terrible name for a function
2. why do you create many varibales `line1,2,3,4,5` if you then  do nothing with them?

Comment: same comment as on other answer: better return something in case `letter != 'k'`

Comment: Well, should I've posted the entire program?
By the way I'm making a "print window" where you write a word and in this window appears the paint of the word. For this reason, I need to know how every line is made.
For example, if I write "HI" I need to know how are the letters "H" and "I" written and then print them

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `string line1;` in `main()` because it's a local variable. in fact, you can't use it outside of the if statement because the `if(letter =='k')` and `void function(char letter)` have different scopes.

Instead of returning void, which is nothing in this case, you should return the string that you would like to use inside of `main()`.

something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string asciiArtALetter(char letterToBox){
    std::string whatToReturn{}; // the {} calls the default constructor for std::string
    if(letterToBox == 'k'){
        whatToReturn = "#   #\n"
                       "#   #\n"
                       "#### \n"
                       "#   #\n"
                       "#   #\n";
    }
    return whatToReturn;
}

int main(){
    auto whatToPrint = asciiArtALetter('k');
    std::cout << whatToPrint << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` or call a function `function` for a couple of reasons. One example of why to avoid this in your case is because of the existence of `std::function`. Another is that you want your code to be self documenting.